# array slice based on custom position logic

Tags: javascript

i have a sorted array, where i need to take the first four elements, but here instead of taking first four i need keep the first and second object static, rest two of them from the sorted array

```js
const data = [
  { symbol: 'EHE', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-46', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-24', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'BHE-67', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'BHE', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-12', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'BHE-23', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-679', name: 'John' },
];



const eheIndex = data.findIndex(item => item.symbol === 'EHE');
const bheIndex = data.findIndex(item => item.symbol === 'BHE');

const output = [
  data[eheIndex],
  data[bheIndex],
  ...data.slice(eheIndex + 1, eheIndex + 3),
];

console.log(output);
```

So this will give me the output placing the first and second object EHE & BHE at top, and rest whatever the remaining from the sorted order.

But if i change the data to a different it doesn't works

```
const notWorkingData = [
  { symbol: 'EHE', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'BHE', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-12', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'BHE-23', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-679', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-46', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'EHE-24', name: 'John' },
  { symbol: 'BHE-67', name: 'John' },
];
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "EHE",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "BHE",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "BHE",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "EHE-12",
        "name": "John"
    }
]
```

This gives me two times the same object where it should take the first and second object one time rest it should take from array order

Expected output

```
[
    {
        "symbol": "EHE",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "BHE",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "BHE-12",
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "symbol": "EHE-23",
        "name": "John"
    }
]
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add a property in first two elements and sort the array by that new property and then by the symbol. after that keep all top 4 elements

Comment: its a sorted array only have this two keys can't add a new property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all indices and map the data.

```js
const
    data = [{ symbol: 'EHE', name: 'John' }, { symbol: 'EHE-46', name: 'John' }, { symbol: 'EHE-24', name: 'John' }, { symbol: 'BHE-67', name: 'John' }, { symbol: 'BHE', name: 'John' }, { symbol: 'EHE-12', name: 'John' }, { symbol: 'BHE-23', name: 'John' }, { symbol: 'EHE-679', name: 'John' }],
    indices = ['EHE', 'BHE'].map(symbol => data.findIndex(item => item.symbol === symbol));

let i = 0;

while (indices.length < 4 && i < data.length) {
    if (!indices.includes(i)) indices.push(i);
    i++;
}

const
    output = indices.map(i => data[i]);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works, just a doubt Instead of using while can we use some array methods to get the output

Comment: the `while` approach is faster than any other built in array method. the problem is to limit only to four items and the wanted items who comes first/second.